# Sencha Touch 2: Web API REST Service Can be consumed on Chrome, but not working on FF and Android APK

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, sencha-touch, cross-domain, crud

I Followed this tutorial:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lsD56AilUxw

http://www.danielgallo.co.uk/post/creating-a-sencha-touch-app-in-sencha-architect-that-communicates-with-a-asp-net-web-api-backend/

on how to consume ASP.NET WebAPi from ST2 App.

I could make it work on google chrome putting ST app on same IIS site than WebApi to prevent cross-domain issues, even I added "Add New" functionality with no problem... but I could notice that was not running on Firefox, only shows NavigationView with no list in there. also, no JS errors.

Even I tried publishing webapi service to test server with an accesible through internet hostname and pointed ST2 app to there. then packaged for android device but same issue at runtime. showing Navigation but no items on list. (tried in emulator and real device)

can you give me a hand on that?

I will really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

When building your native application, you are running into the same problem that you had before with Chrome - cross-domain issues.  You cannot use standard AJAX calls using Sencha Touch native apps alone.

The only solution when using only Sencha Touch is to use a JSON-P proxy: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.JsonP

Another possible solution is to use something like PhoneGap (Cordova) to allow for cross-domain requests like this.  You can then [whitelist](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html) your server to allow for these requests.

Comment: I tried phonegap solution adding access-origin="*" to config.xml with no success...also tried using JSONP proxy but other issues has been presented...thanks anyway...